# CPP and Java giving different output

Tags: java, c++

I have two sets of code. One in CPP and other one in java. Both sets of code seem to be same but they are giving me different outputs. I am fully confused here. I am new to cpp. Please help.

CPP code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int helper(vector<vector<int> > table, int i, int j) {
    if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= 4 || j >= 4 ) return 0;
    if ( table[i][j] == 1 ) return 0;
    if ( i == 3 && j == 3 ) return 1;

    table[i][j] = 1;
    return helper(table, i, j+1) + helper(table, i+1, j) + helper(table, i, j-1) + helper(table, i-1, j);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<vector<int> > table;
    vector<int> x(4,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        table.push_back(x);


    cout << helper(table, 0, 0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 184
Link : http://cpp.sh/2xeee

Java Code:

```
public class Solution{


    int helper(int[][] table, int i, int j) {
        if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= 4 || j >= 4 ) return 0;
        if ( table[i][j] == 1 ) return 0;
        if ( i == 3 && j == 3 ) return 1;

        table[i][j] = 1;
        return helper(table, i, j+1) + helper(table, i+1, j) + helper(table, i, j-1) + helper(table, i-1, j);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] table=new int[4][4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) table[i][j]=0;
        System.out.println(new Solution().helper(table,0,0));
    }


}
```

Output : 2 
link : http://ideone.com/e.js/U9X1FX

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *Both sets of code seem to be same* -- Java is not C++.  Just because the code looks the same, it isn't.

Comment: You don't need the loop that fills the `table` array with zeros. Java number arrays are always pre-filled with 0.

Comment: *I am fully confused here. I am new to cpp* -- Also, don't use Java as a model in writing or learning C++.  You'll just be more confused when other things don't work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In java, the table is handed over to the helper by reference. In C++, the table is copied on each call.

To make C++ behave like java, change the helper call to take a reference:

```
int helper(vector<vector<int> >& table, int i, int j) {
```

**Edit**: To make Java behave like the original C++ code, you'll need to copy the affected parts of the table. Change the helper to this:

```
int helper(int[][] original, int i, int j) {
    if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= 4 || j >= 4 ) return 0;
    if ( original[i][j] == 1 ) return 0;
    if ( i == 3 && j == 3 ) return 1;

    int[] table = new int[4][];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, table, 0, 4);
    table[i] = new int[4];
    System.arraycopy(original[i], 0, table[i], 0, 4);

    table[i][j] = 1;

    return helper(table, i, j+1) + helper(table, i+1, j) + helper(table, i, j-1) + helper(table, i-1, j);
}
```

Comment: How can i make here java behave like cpp?  @Stefan Haustein

Comment: That's more work: In helper, rename the table parameter to original, then construct a new table with all the elements copied from original.

Comment: p.s. You only need to copy if you change the table

Comment: i imported java.lang.System and still getting error  Solution.java:16: error: method arraycopy in class System cannot be applied to given types;
     System.arraycopy(original[i], 0, table[i], 4);
           ^
  required: Object,int,Object,int,int
  found: int[],int,int[],int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: Oops, needs to be 0, 4 at the end